# How do I enabled "include tags" on a push by default in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When I push from TortoiseGit, tags are not included by default.  In a recent update, however, an option was added to help with this.  There is now a check box in the push dialog to "include tags".  How do I set this to enabled by default?

I don't want to forget to add the check when I want to push a tag.  A this point, I don't use any tags locally which I don't want to push and thus share with other developers.

I tried adding

```
[push]
  followTags = true
```

to my gitconfig file (local, global, systemwide, tgitconfig...) which TortoiseGit lets you edit from Settings->Git, but that neither set the switch, nor performed the action when I pushed...

Comment: Did you find a way now?

Comment: No.  I have yet to solve this one.  Please post a solution if you come up with it.  I have noted where other git gui tools have had this as an option as well, but had it turned on by default instead...

Comment: I've yet to see an option to make this work, all this time later...  In case it helps anyone, I did note that when viewing the change log / commit history, you can right-click on a tag and select to push it independently / directly.

Answer (score 1):

As of today TortoiseGit (v. 2.1.0) doesn't remember the "push tags" state.

---

However, as a workaround you can configure your remote you push to to always push all tags, e.g. put something like that in your `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    push = ... (your old push line)
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

The `+` at the beginning indicates to force push all remote tags (remove the prefix in order to prevent that).

Comment: I just tried this on 2.3.  It didn't work for me.  Perhaps I'm missing a detail? I pasted your push line exactly as is into the local gitconfig of a repo, added a tag and a commit. I pushed, and the commit went through, but no tag...

Comment: I tried enabling forced push on the server in case that was needed, but it had no effect.